# Why does Amazon Video works on Google Chrome but not on chromium (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I tried firefox, opera, chromium and google chrome. Why does amazon video only works with google chrome?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to access it with Chromium?  Have you got Flash installed?

Comment: To answer "why?" requires knowing what's different between your browsers (things like plug-ins, add-ons, configuration, settings for ad blockers and tracking blockers, etc.).

Comment: "your web browser is not compatible with amazon video. Please use google chrome". I have no flash installed. I should mention that i am using amazon.de (germany).
No Plugin activated. Does chrome have any additional drm functionality that chromium doesn't have?

Comment: Chrome supports Amazon's HTML5 player on Linux.  Other browsers do not, and so they require a working/compatible Flash plug-in so they can use Amazon's flash player instead of the HTML5 player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome uses the Widevine plugin that is required by Amazon's HTML5 player to playback protected premium content.

Comment: Is Widevine plugin available for chromium as well?

Comment: I think maybe in some platforms. However, it is not officially supported for various reasons: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429452 has the discussion in case you want to follow.

Comment: There seems to be a PPA available for chromium with Widevine support https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1371274

Comment: This is out of date. The latest versions of Firefox ship with the widevine plugin. You can see this by gong add-ons, and plugins. But it still won't let you playback HD content.